# How to redirect all 404 errors

Tags: swift, vapor

How would I catch all 404 errors and redirect to /app/index.html (I'm trying to satisfy Angular's need to forward all not found resources to index.html) ? I thought implementing my own middleware would work, but not sure I'm doing it right

```
public final class ForwardToAngularMiddleware: Middleware {
    public func respond(to req: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
        do {
            let response: Future<Response> = try next.respond(to: req)
            return response
        } catch let error as AbortError {
            if error.status == .notFound && req.http.url.path.starts(with: "/app") {
                return Future.map(on: req) { req.redirect(to: "/index.html") }
            }
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

My program never hits the catch block no matter what URL I send. I am configuring my middleware like this:

```
middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self)
middlewares.use(ForwardToAngularMiddleware())
middlewares.use(ErrorMiddleware.self)
middlewares.use(SessionsMiddleware.self)
services.register(middlewares)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be hitting a couple of issues here. First, the abort error could be being thrown in a future, in which case you need to add a `catchMap` to the `next.respond(to:)` call to catch that case.

It also may not throw (though this is unlikely), so you can try unwrapping the response and checking the status code.

Have you put a breakpoint in to see if it ever hits it etc?

Comment: Thanks! that was it; I needed to use catchMap

Comment: @D.C. could you maybe share your updated solution?